# Group a list of dates by month, year

Tags: python, list, datetime, pandas, group-by

```
raw_data = ["2015-12-31", "2015-12-1" , "2015-1-1",
            "2014-12-31", "2014-12-1" , "2014-1-1",
            "2013-12-31", "2013-12-1" , "2013-1-1",]
expected_grouped_bymonth = [("2015-12", #dates_in_the_list_occured_in_december_2015)
                            , ...
                            ("2013-1",  #january2013dates)]
```

OR as a dict

```
expected_grouped_bymonth = {
    "2015-12": #dates_in_the_list_occured_in_december_2015) , ...
    "2013-1", #january2013dates)}
```

I have a list of strings that represent dates. What I would like to have is a list of tuples, or a dictionary, that count per year or month the number of occurrences. What I've tried to do is something related to the `groupby`. I'm not able to understand how to use the the `TimeGrouper` according to the `groupby` function.

The raised exception is:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex,
           but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

from itertools import groupby
for el in data:
    if 'Real rates - Real volatilities' in el['scenario']:
        counter += 1
        real_records_dates.append(pd.to_datetime(el['refDate']))
print("Thera are {} real records.".format(counter))

BY_YEAR = 'Y'
BY_MONTH = 'M'
BY_DAY = 'D'

real_records_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(real_records_dates))

real_records_df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq=BY_MONTH))
```

(You can also assume to start with a dictionary og `{date1:1, date2:2, ...}` if it easier. My problem is related only to the `groupby`.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a sample of exactly what is in `data`.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: the expected_grouped_bymonth; basically I need to group the list of dates by the month / or the year  and as a group function I need to compute how many dates occur in the active month/year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the frequency of how often a date occurs per month and year you can use a *defaulftdict*:

```
raw_data = ["2015-12-31", "2015-12-1", "2015-1-1",
        "2014-12-31", "2014-12-1", "2014-1-1",
        "2013-12-31", "2013-12-1", "2013-1-1",
        ]

from collections import defaultdict

dates = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))

for s in raw_data:
    k, v = s.rsplit("-", 1)
    dates[k][v] += 1

print(dates)
```

Or if you just want to *Group a list of dates by month, year*:

```
dates = defaultdict(list)

for s in raw_data:
    k, v = s.rsplit("-", 1)
    dates[k].append(v)

print(dates)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! May I ask you if there is an equivalent manner to do it with the groupby function?
That the main objective of my doubt!

Comment: @LeoCella, do you mean putting our grouped dates in a df and applying the groupby or just passing the dates and then performing a groupby?

Comment: starting from the list of dates, use the groupby to aggregate them by month or year, and keeping the count of their frequencies. If it is necessary I can also start with dictionaries {initialdate1:1,..initialdaten:1} to use like sum function in the groupby. I don't know if it's possible, is just an idea similar to SQL procedures.